# Conditional formating in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I'm a Crystal report (11)  newb - Within a report I have a field for a vehicle VIN (Vehicle Identification Number).  Right now the VIN prints simply as   VIN: 1FAHP3438YW374102 .  I would like to apply conditonal formating so the data would print the last 6 character in bold such as:

VIN: 1FAHP3438YW**374102**

Can that be done with a formula?

JD

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in two steps. The first is to use the formula below. The second is to go into the "Format Field" dialog box and change the "Text Interpretation" to "HTML Text".

```
NumberVar x := 5; // you don't need a variable but it doesn't hurt 

// left part of string 
left({Command.VIN_NUMBER},len({Command.VIN_NUMBER}) - x) + 

// begin HTML tag for bold
"<b>" + 

// right part of string
right({Command.VIN_NUMBER},x) + 

// end HTML tag for bold
"</b>"
```

Comment: Perfect -  works perfectly.  Could I be greedy?  :) Could the formula also put a space between the highlighted and non highlighted characters?

Comment: Sure. Just concatenate a space in there.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to create two formula fields, then embed them in a text object.  Once embedded, you have a wide-range of formatting options.

```
//{@left}
{Command.VIN_NUMBER}[1 to 11]

//{@right}
{Command.VIN_NUMBER}[12 to Len({Command.VIN_NUMBER})]
```